# Brewster angle and perpendicular component

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

Fresnel's equations give that at Brewster's angle, the parallel component of the incident light is zero. The reflected perpendicular component is not zero, though. We can "remove" this component using multiple plates. Assume we have 'N' plates. How can I formulate a relation for the power of the perpendicular component as it passes through these N plates at Brewster's angle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method is to use the transfer matrix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer-matrix_method_(optics)

Your question is actually related to a recent Science paper: http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1249799